# VBA word active x control

Tags: vba, ms-word, calculation

I am trying to make this VBA macro works to calculate two sets of data using active x controls in ms-word. For each box in the table

[image]

I want the calculation to give the number of count each time "2" is checked off as true of the S1A to S1D AND S2A TO S2D on Label1.caption.

And another set of calculations will give the number of count each time "2" is checked off as true of the T1A to T1D AND T2A to T2D with the output at Label2.caption.

Below is what I have started but it does not achieve what I am trying to.

```
enter code here
Dim count_of_0 As Integer
Dim count_of_2 As Integer
Sub calculate_the_score()
count_of_0 = 0
count_of_2 = 0

If S1A.Value = True Then count_of_0 = count_of_0 + 0
If S2A.Value = True Then count_of_2 = count_of_2 + 2

If S1B.Value = True Then count_of_0 = count_of_0 + 0
If S2B.Value = True Then count_of_2 = count_of_2 + 2

If S1C.Value = True Then count_of_0 = count_of_0 + 0
If S2C.Value = True Then count_of_2 = count_of_2 + 2

If S1D.Value = True Then count_of_0 = count_of_0 + 0
If S2D.Value = True Then count_of_2 = count_of_2 + 2

If T1A.Value = True Then count_of_0 = count_of_0 + 0
If T2A.Value = True Then count_of_2 = count_of_2 + 2

If T1B.Value = True Then count_of_0 = count_of_0 + 0
If T2B.Value = True Then count_of_2 = count_of_2 + 2

If T1C.Value = True Then count_of_0 = count_of_0 + 0
If T2C.Value = True Then count_of_2 = count_of_2 + 2

If T1D.Value = True Then count_of_0 = count_of_0 + 0
If T2D.Value = True Then count_of_2 = count_of_2 + 2    

Dim the_sum As Double

the_sum = (count_of_0) + (count_of_2)

Label1.Caption = "Total:" & the_sum & ""
Label2.caption = "Total :" & the_sum & ""
End Sub


Private Sub S1A_Click()
 If S1A = True Then
    S2A = False
 End If
 calculate_the_score
End Sub

Private Sub S1B_Click()
 If S1B = True Then
    S2B = False
End If
 calculate_the_score
End Sub

Private Sub S1C_Click()
 If S1C = True Then
    S2C = False
 End If
 calculate_the_score
End Sub

Private Sub S1D_Click()
 If S1D = True Then
    S2D = False
 End If
  calculate_the_score
End Sub

Private Sub S2A_Click()
 If S2A = True Then
    S1A = False
 End If
 calculate_the_score
End Sub

Private Sub S2B_Click()
 If S2B = True Then
    S1B = False
 End If
 calculate_the_score
End Sub

Private Sub S2C_Click()
 If S2C = True Then
    S1C = False
 End If
 calculate_the_score
End Sub

Private Sub S2D_Click()
 If S2D = True Then
    S1D = False
 End If
 calculate_the_score



Private Sub T1A_Click()
 If T1A = True Then
    T2A = False
 End If
 calculate_the_score
End Sub

Private Sub T1B_Click()
 If T1B = True Then
    T2B = False
 End If
 calculate_the_score
End Sub

Private Sub T1C_Click()
 If T1C = True Then
    T2C = False
 End If
 calculate_the_score
End Sub

Private Sub T1D_Click()
 If T1D = True Then
    T2D = False
 End If
 calculate_the_score
End Sub

Private Sub T2A_Click()
 If T2A = True Then
    T1A = False
 End If
 calculate_the_score
End Sub

Private Sub T2B_Click()
 If T2B = True Then
    T1B = False
 End If
 calculate_the_score
End Sub

Private Sub T2C_Click()
 If T2C = True Then
    T1C = False
 End If
 calculate_the_score
End Sub

Private Sub T2D_Click()
 If T2D = True Then
    T1D = False
 End If
 calculate_the_score
End Sub
```

Comment: *"Below is what I have started but it does not achieve what I am trying to."* - please be more specific, what is the current behavior and what is the expected outcome?

Comment: In addition, we have no idea what `S1A to S1D AND S2A TO S2D on Label1.caption` and `T1A to T1D AND T2A to T2D with the output at Label2.caption` are. What you have and what you want are not at all clear to anyone reading this - we don't have the background knowledge of the project.

Comment: @Dwirony, it is adding up the count of both the checkboxes names from S1A to S1D and S2A to S2D alonf with the T1A to T1D AND T2A to T2D. I am looking to have label1.caption to give me the SUM of the count for S2A to S2D. and label2.caption to give me the SUM of T2A to T2D when checked off as true.

Comment: @cindy Meister, S1A, S1B, S1C and S1D are the names of the checkboxes that have the "0" value even if checked off as true (0 value even if checked off and the sum would be still 0) . S2A, S2B, S2C and S2D are the names of the checkboxes that have values "2" when checked off. The output of this first calculation should go to the label1.caption as sum of the values checked off as true.

Comment: @M.R. When you click a box, what shows up on your label captions, 0?

Comment: @ Cindy Meister. And I want to repeat the same thing for T1A to T1D (0 value even if checked off and the sum would be still 0). And T2A to T2D have values "2" and the sum of these values checked off as true should go to the output label2.caption.

Comment: @M.R. What is `count_of_0 + 0`? `count_of_0` is never going to be anything other than 0...?

Comment: @dwirony, label1.caption and label2.caption give the same total of the sum of the checkboxes. I want to separate the sum output the two set of checkboxes

Comment: @dwirony, I jwas trying to be as details as possible and added that but you are right it will be always 0. What I am interested at is the non-zero.

Comment: @dwirony, any suggestion to make this work? never mind about the count_of_0. How can I get the sum of the S2A to S2D to label1 and the sum of T2A to T2D to output on label2? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: @M.R. So you want label1 to display the 0s and label2 to display the 2s sum?

Comment: @dwirony, I don't need to display the count of 0s. I need to display the count_of_2 from S2A to S2D on label1 and the count_of_2 from T2A to T2D on label2.

Comment: @M.R. Okay I understand now. I'll post some code in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Dim count_of_0 As Integer
Dim scount_of_2 As Integer
Dim tcount_of_2 As Integer
Sub calculate_the_score()
count_of_0 = 0
scount_of_2 = 0
tcount_of_2 = 0

If S1A.Value = True Then count_of_0 = count_of_0 + 0
If S2A.Value = True Then scount_of_2 = scount_of_2 + 2

If S1B.Value = True Then count_of_0 = count_of_0 + 0
If S2B.Value = True Then scount_of_2 = scount_of_2 + 2

If S1C.Value = True Then count_of_0 = count_of_0 + 0
If S2C.Value = True Then scount_of_2 = scount_of_2 + 2

If S1D.Value = True Then count_of_0 = count_of_0 + 0
If S2D.Value = True Then scount_of_2 = scount_of_2 + 2

If T1A.Value = True Then count_of_0 = count_of_0 + 0
If T2A.Value = True Then tcount_of_2 = tcount_of_2 + 2

If T1B.Value = True Then count_of_0 = count_of_0 + 0
If T2B.Value = True Then tcount_of_2 = tcount_of_2 + 2

If T1C.Value = True Then count_of_0 = count_of_0 + 0
If T2C.Value = True Then tcount_of_2 = tcount_of_2 + 2

If T1D.Value = True Then count_of_0 = count_of_0 + 0
If T2D.Value = True Then tcount_of_2 = tcount_of_2 + 2

Label1.Caption = "Total:" & scount_of_2 & ""
Label2.Caption = "Total :" & tcount_of_2 & ""

End Sub
```

Comment: the syntax makes sense but I will test it tonight.

Comment: you are the man!! the syntax works perfectly and returns the functions I intended to achieve. Thank you very much! I hope I can give you 5 Stars!!! Thank you again!!!!!!